# how to cycle through slides on basic js slider

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a basic slider with Previous and Next buttons and Im trying to figure out how to scroll through the slides and add/remove a class to the relevant slides while cycling. Please can I get some help.

Heres what I have so far,I'd like the previous and next links to cycle through the slides adding and removing classes as it goes. Hope that makes sense.

Thanks.

Codepen : https://codepen.io/ukscotth/pen/LYERPvJ

HTML

```
<div class="slider-container">

  <div class="slide show" data-index="1">   
    <div class="image-container">
      <div class="image" style="background-image:url('https://images.pexels.com/photos/3233372/pexels-photo-3233372.jpeg');">
      </div>
    </div>   
    <div class="info-container">
      <h1>Slide 1 Title</h1>
      <h4>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua.</h4>
    </div>   
  </div>

   <div class="slide" data-index="2">   
    <div class="image-container">
      <div class="image" style="background-image:url('https://images.pexels.com/photos/3268443/pexels-photo-3268443.jpeg');">
      </div>
    </div>   
    <div class="info-container">
      <h1>Slide 2 Title</h1>
      <h4>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua.</h4>
    </div>   
  </div>

<div class="prev-button">PREV</div>
<div class="next-button">NEXT</div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.slider-container {
  width:100%;
  padding:50px;
}

.slide {
  position:absolute;
  opacity:0; 
}
.slide.show {
  opacity:1; 
}

.image-container{
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right:30px;
}

.image {
  width:300px;
  height:300px;
  background-size:cover;
}

.info-container{
  display: inline-block;
  width:300px;
  vertical-align: top;
}

.prev-button{
  position:absolute;
  top:400px;
  left:150px;
}
.next-button{
  position:absolute;
  top:400px;
  left:250px;
}
```

JS

```
(function($) {
  "use strict";

  var count;
  $count = 1;

  $('.next-button').click(function(e) {
    $('.slide[data-index=2]').addClass('show');
  });                         

})(jQuery);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace the next and prev function as below and it works. You just have to use a simple logic........

```
          $('.next-button').click(function(e) {  


        if(active==4){
          prev = 4; active = 1; next = 2;
          $('.slide[data-index='+active+']').addClass('show');
          $('.slide[data-index='+prev+']').removeClass('show'); 
        } else {

            $('.slide[data-index='+active+']').removeClass('show'); 
            $('.slide[data-index='+next+']').addClass('show'); 
            if (prev == 4) {
                prev = 0;
            }
            prev++; 
            active++;
            next++;
        }

        console.log('prev'+prev);
        console.log('active'+active);
        console.log('next'+next);
      });

      $('.prev-button').click(function(e) {  

        if(active==1){
          prev = 3; active = 4; next = 1;
          $('.slide[data-index='+active+']').addClass('show');
          $('.slide[data-index='+next+']').removeClass('show'); 
        } else {
            $('.slide[data-index='+active+']').removeClass('show'); 
            $('.slide[data-index='+prev+']').addClass('show'); 
            prev--; 
            active--;
            if (next == 1) {
                next = 5;
            }
            next--;
        }


        console.log('prev'+prev);
        console.log('active'+active);
        console.log('next'+next);
      });
```

Comment: Awesome thanks a lot :) now i just need to work out how to do the autoplay part lol. Any ideas how ? thanks again.

Comment: Actually forget that, I worked it out. Didnt realise how simple it was :)

Answer (score 0):

I have done my own slider before. I can give you an idea.
when "next" is pressed, remove the "show" class from the current slide, increment the index and add the "show" class to the next. When the current index is the maximum, make the next index to "1".

If you want to automate the slider, have a time interval

setInterval( "slideSwitch()", 5000 ); //this will run slideSwitch every 5 seconds.

Inside this function, add the "show" class to next slide and remove the "show" class to previous(current) slide.

Hope this idea helps.....

Comment: Thanks, ive managed to get it working with the next button, but cant seem to be able to do it with the previous button, any ideas ? ive updated my codepen. https://codepen.io/ukscotth/pen/LYERPvJ

Answer (score 0):

Try to put the "if" statement first.....

```
  $('.prev-button').click(function(e) {  

    if(active==1){
      prev = 4; active = 1; next = 2;
      // comment this out...$('.slide[data-index='+active+']').addClass('show');
    }

    $('.slide[data-index='+active+']').removeClass('show'); 
    $('.slide[data-index='+prev+']').addClass('show'); 
    prev--; 
    active--;
    next--;


    console.log('prev'+prev);
    console.log('active'+active);
    console.log('next'+next);
  });
```

Comment: Still not working unfortunately, i've updated the codepen to show you what it's doing now. Thanks.